# ｎ進グレイコードからｎ進表記へ戻すには？

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

ｎ進グレイコードの出力を行った
（参考：[ｎ進グレイコードの出力について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10238/%EF%BD%8E%E9%80%B2%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)）
ので、その逆をやってみました。

```
# n進表記から n進グレイコードへ
def to_gray(n, k, str)
  str.rjust(k + 1, '0').split('').each_cons(2).map{|d| (d[1].to_i - d[0].to_i) % n}.join
end

# n進グレイコードから n進表記へ
def to_n_ary(n, k, str)
  ary0 = str.rjust(k, '0').split('')
  d = ary0[0].to_i
  n_ary = [d]
  (1..k - 1).each{|e|
    d = (d + ary0[e].to_i) % n
    n_ary << d
  }
  n_ary.join
end

n, k = 2, 3
ary = []
(0..n ** k - 1).each{|i| ary << to_n_ary(n, k, to_gray(n, k, i.to_s(n)))}
p ary # n進表記に戻っているはず
```

さて上記コードにおいて、
①**n > 10 のとき上手くいかない**のですが、
　どのように修正すればよろしいでしょうか？
②to_gray(n, k, str) の逆操作を to_n_ary(n, k, str)
　で行なっているわけですが、
　to_n_ary(n, k, str)
　をもう少し短く書くにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(編集: `n > 10` に対応しました)

① `n > 10` の場合でも正しく動作させるには `to_i`, `to_s` に `n` を指定すれば良いです。

1. `.to_i` を `.to_i(n)` にする
2. `.join` の実行前に `.to_s(n)` を明示的に行う

`to_gray` も修正が必要になりますね:

```
def to_gray(n, k, str)
  str.rjust(k + 1, '0').split('').each_cons(2).map{|d|
    ((d[1].to_i(n) - d[0].to_i(n)) % n).to_s(n)
  }.join
end
```

② やっている事は質問のコードと基本的に同じで、書き方を変えただけですが:

```
def to_n_ary(n, k, str)
  a = 0
  str.rjust(k, '0').split('').map{|d| ((a += d.to_i(n)) % n).to_s(n)}.join
end
```

n進数にした時の先頭の 0 を除くならば(この場合引数 k は使いませんね):

```
def to_n_ary(n, k, str)
  a = 0
  str.sub(/^0+(?!$)/, '').split('').map{|d| ((a += d.to_i(n)) % n).to_s(n)}.join
end
```